# Gaussian beam from a CO2 laser

Tags: laser

What is required to make a Gaussian beam from a diffraction grating CO2 laser? If a non Gaussian (non TEM00) mode is obtained, is that due to a symmetry problem somewhere in the laser, which could be fixed by a better alignment? Attached is a picture of the spot about 8 metres away from the CO2 laser output coupler.

[image: CO2 laser spot 8m away.]

Comment: Maybe you could post a photo of the mode you are getting. I've never played around with laser alignment, but I'd think your hypothesis is a good one. The laser's output is an eigenfunction of the operator that describes the round trip through the cavity - if that round trip contains skewing of the beam or other asymmetries, then that's going to show up in the output. If the output has a plane of symmetry, then that's a hint that the misalignment is in the orthogonal direction.

Comment: Donut shaped but it might be a 11 mode that has blurred together? See above